# Launch two xterm and ssh into servers automatically

Tags: bash, ssh, xterm, sshpass

I'm using the following bash script and it has a couple of issues:

1. The second xterm doesn't launch until the first is killed
2. I've got to kill each xterm launched with quit instead of simply $exit
3. The bash terminal I run the script from is locked until both xterms have been killed
4. I would like to change directories after launching xterm and ssh into server

   ```
   read -s -p "PW? " password

   xterm -bg red -fg yellow -hold -e sshpass -p $password ssh user@server1

   xterm -bg blue -fg yellow -hold -e sshpass -p $password ssh user@server2
   ```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

The solutions provided allowed me to create the following that works perfectly:

```
xterm -bg red -fg yellow -e sshpass -p $password ssh -Y -t user@server1 'cd /home/user/work; $SHELL -i' &
xterm -bg blue -fg yellow -e sshpass -p $password ssh -Y -t user@server2 'cd /home/user/work/; $SHELL -i' &
```

Comment: need more details for q4: you mean on the remote shell session, you want to cd to some dir and then continue in the interactive shell?

Comment: Yes. I need to use those windows for the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions (1) and (3) are solved by launching the xterms in the background:

```
xterm -bg red  -fg yellow -hold -e sshpass -p $password ssh user@server1  &
xterm -bg blue -fg yellow -hold -e sshpass -p $password ssh user@server2  &
```

Question (4), you can do more interesting things with `expect`, but this should do (tested only with ssh, not with xterm and sshpass):

```
xterm -bg blue -fg yellow -hold -e sshpass -p $password ssh -t user@server2 'cd /var/log; $SHELL -i'  &
```

It assumes your SHELL understands `-i` to mean "an interactive shell".
Note the addition of the `-t` option to ssh.

Comment: Note, you must quote your password everywhere: `"$password"`

Comment: @glennjackman Didn't want to write a completely new answer for the last 25% when you already covered the first 75%... Feel free to add it to your answer if you want...